# California tax residency for TN visa

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, visa, tax-residency

I am a Canadian citizen working in California on a TN visa. I worked 4.5 months in 2016 and plan to continue working here indefinitely. Am I considered a tax resident for 2016?

Comment: This link says TN visa holders are always non-residents: https://students.ucsd.edu/finances/fees/residence/noncitizens.html#Adult-aliens. Is there official documentation supporting this claim?

Comment: Are you also a college student? The link is determining residence status for tuition. purposes.

Comment: Oh I see. I am not a college student.

Comment: @fumoboy007: That's state residency for tuition purposes. It has nothing to do with taxes.

Comment: I will also note that if you don't have income from outside California in the period of time you're resident in California, whether you count as a resident or nonresident for California taxes won't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You want [FTB Publication 1031: Guidelines for Determining Resident Status](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2016/16_1031.pdf). And if you still have questions, the assistance of a professional tax preparer.

Armchair version: you're likely a California resident for tax purposes.